# Backbone.marionette re-render view on model change

Tags: marionette

//when i click the kickassessor button, it will update the database but the view isn't updating. Here is my code.
    return Marionette.ItemView.extend( {

```
    initialize : function ( options ) {
        var self = this;

        _.bindAll( this );

        _.each( options, function ( value, key ) {
            self[ key ] = value;
        } );
        //this.model.on('change', this.render, this);

        return this;
    },


    // Ui events hash
    events : {
        'mouseover a.btn'  : 'showTooltip',
        'click #kickBtn'   : 'kickAssessor',
        'click #deleteBtn' : 'deleteUser'
    },

    // on render callback
    onRender : function() {
        this.ui.kickBtn.tooltip( {
            title : 'Kick as assessor'
        } );

        this.ui.deleteBtn.tooltip( {
            title : 'Delete user'
        } );
    },

    kickAssessor : function ( ) {
        this.model.save({role:'2'});
                    //on success it should update the itemview
    },
```

Answer (score 10):

You can add a `modelEvents` hash (https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#modelevents-and-collectionevents):

```
modelEvents: {
  "sync": "render"
}
```

The above will call the `render` function each time your model syncs with the server.

Comment: i tried this solution but still isn't working.it doesn't update the view//modelEvents: {
            'change': 'modelChanged'
        },

    modelChanged: function() {
        //console.log('model change');
        this.render();
 }

Comment: Just noticed the way you're updating the model (by calling `save`) doesn't trigger a "change" event. I've updated my answer to use the "sync" event, which will be triggered when the server responds to the `save` call.

Comment: Remember, the onShow event only gets called on initial rendering, not re-rendering.